# SaltStack: Disable Cron during run

Tags: saltstack

I would like to disable cron on the minion when salt gets executed.

Disabling it would be easy: [service.disabled](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.service.html#salt.states.service.disabled)

But how to enable it again (in all cases (success or error))?

What I want is comparable with a context-manager in the python programming language.

Answer (score 1):

All states are executed, even when some failed, if they do not `require` a failed one. So you could start with a `service.dead`, some other states, then a `service.running` at the end.

I don't understand why you would want that, though.

Comment: AFAIK `failhard` does brake this. If a failhard state fails, then no other states get executed. But I am unsure. Maybe I am wrong: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/failhard.html#state-level-failhard

Comment: Yes, that's the purpose of failhard, indeed.

Comment: I understand the need because we have the same with apticron when running integration tests. Sometimes, during tests, apticron run and this make highstate fail (because /var/cache/apt locked). So we configure apticron to never run when running tests.